Are Blue State companies moving to Texas primarily due to the political leanings of their top executives?
California seems to be really hard hit—it has lost to Texas the North American headquarters of Toyota, HP, Oracle (which pulled a "move to Texas" on Texas by relocating to Tennessee), and all of Musk's companies, which benefited significantly from subsidies in California, including tax breaks and regulatory credits that were crucial during their early growth. Most recently, Chevron has decided to relocate, claiming that its employees didn’t want to be transferred to California.
Is there any evidence that companies that "moved to Texas" from blue states have done better for themselves after the move? Or are these moves primarily driven by the political leanings of top executives (with Musk being a prime example)?
For all the hype about crime in California, statistics show that when it comes to crime, Texas and California are comparable. As for cost of living, Texas does have an advantage, but many people prefer California for its magnificent weather and are willing to endure a higher cost of living for that.

Welcome to the site! Politics is a site for asking about governments, policies and political processes. You're asking about the internal motivations of private individuals, the business decisions they're making with their companies, and the results of those business decisions. While political beliefs may factor in to those decisions, your question doesn't actually seem to be about the government or political side of things.

This needs clarification before reopening: it seems to ask several different things: why the companies moved or said they moved (for which you need to list specific companies), whether they've done better or worse, and what the benefits or disbenefits of California and Texas are. It's also not clear if you're only interested in companies moving from California. Focus on the political element, not crime or taxes.

FWTW, just digging up one of your examples.

A $40 million state incentive package was one of many reasons Toyota agreed to move its headquarters to Plano, company CEO Jim Lentz said Thursday. Yet absent the subsidy, picking Texas would have been a "real tough sell."
[...] Lentz pointed to a long list of factors that drove the company’s decision to move to Texas, including the availability of affordable land and a lower cost of living for employees.
“Incentives are part of that process but we are not a company that’s going to say, ‘Whoever is going to give us the largest incentive, that’s where we’re going to go,’” Lentz said. “That would be foolish to do.”
Texas' business-friendly environment was also an obvious draw, Lentz said, but so was the Dallas area's political diversity.
[...] The state’s $40 million package was based on Toyota’s commitment to bring 4,000 jobs to Texas. Speaking to reporters after Thursday's event, Lentz expressed confidence that the company would have no trouble reaching the job creation target and collecting the full subsidy.

And

North Carolina business recruiters offered Toyota more than $100 million in incentives for the world’s largest carmaker to move its North American headquarters to Charlotte rather than a Dallas suburb, but still lost out to a Texas offer half that size.
[...] North Carolina’s offer had to be significantly larger than Texas to be competitive because the Lone Star State has no corporate or income tax, Commerce Secretary Sharon Decker said in an interview last week. Companies on the move compare the total cost of its new site and the total financial package offered to coax them, Decker said.
“Incentives were just one of many considerations” Toyota considered including geography, transportation, the cost of living and educational opportunities, Mike Michels, a spokesman for Torrance, Calif.-based Toyota Motor Sales U.S.A. Inc., said in an emailed statement. Toyota’s manufacturing plants are in Texas, Kentucky, Mississippi and Indiana.

So, long-term advantages trump short-term/one-off incentives, at least with some companies.
BTW, in the EU, Ireland was famous for attracting corporate HQs for the same low(er) tax reasons and not much having to do with their Catholic values. (Note: lower relative to the rest of EU.)

As a general rule, corporations have only one interest: profit. If they move offices between US states, it's almost invariably because they are looking for:

better tax rates
more favorable regulatory structures
more cost-effective workforces
grants, exemptions, or subsidies
other fiscal or material advantages

Corporate CEOs typically use political talking points as bargaining chips or excuses, not as foundational reasons. CEOs sometimes threaten to move to wheedle more favorable policies from their current locale, sometimes use political language to obscure less savory reasons for moves they want to make (e.g., to get looser pollution standards), and sometimes use political language as a form of lobbying. But they don't generally move a corporation for political reasons. Relocating is costly, the reward for doing it has to offset the investment in the move, and political ideology (like warfare) produces nothing at excessive rates.
Elon Musk (like Mike Lindell) is an outlier, willing to risk his personal fortune and corporate holdings to achieve political ends. I won't speculate on why that is — I could, mind you — but it is not normal behavior for a corporate leader to incur and accept significant financial hits just to be a political dilettante. But these are the times we live in…

Might be worth noting that even those who move to another state after securing a deal won't always stay for the term of the deal and will move to another state or country if they find something better.

I wouldn't be surprised if Musk follows in Trump's steps and runs for president at one point. Ah, I forgot he's not born in the US...

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever: Yeah, well, that won't stop him running for emperor…

UPDATE:
It suggested that I am right leaning. I am not. I am stating what is being reported by companies that have or are considering to move from CA. To DV an answer in "Politics SE" not because of poor cites or bad logic, but perceived right leaning? That my friends is sad.
First understand why someone with a fiduciary duty would move a business.
It costs a hell of lot to move and it is very disruptive to a business. The receiving state might provide incentives to offset costs along with the lessor taxes. But there must be a business reason to move a business other than "I didn't like the current politics" if a CEO wants to keep their jobs.
What are the overwhelming reasons to leave?
Taxes and threats of new taxes.
Regulations and threats of new regulations
Cost of living in CA is typically higher than most placing in the US. But more so in recent years.
In some locations, employee safety is now a concern:
https://reformcalifornia.org/news/heres-a-list-of-companies-fleeing-san-francisco-and-why
https://www.scbc-law.org/post/the-corporate-departure-from-california#:~:text=The%20California%20Policy%20Institute%20counted,left%20the%20state%20since%202005.
CA even has a new tax for businesses exiting the state!
https://paragonaccountants.com/navigating-the-california-exit-tax-what-you-need-to-know-before-leaving-the-golden-state/#:~:text=The%20California%20exit%20tax%20is,the%20wealth%20of%20state%20residents.
CA fiscal issues are well known:
https://calmatters.org/explainers/california-budget-whiplash/
Already the top 1% of earners paid about half of the personal income taxes. This is despite the "don't pay their fair share" hyperbole.
CA has been proposing adding taxes on business above certain sizes and wealth taxes.
These things make it harder to have capital to invest and grow a business.
The economics of taxing businesses is such that is money is taxed twice. Once for the business and again either by the shareholder or the employee.
https://www.nber.org/reporter/2023number3/how-do-corporate-taxes-affect-economic-activity
Bottomline is CA is not currently a business friendly state. Not only that, proposals are to make it less business friendly in the coming year.
Does that mean "Right Leaning" CEOs will tend to move? It might help them happier with the decision, but it is not likely the reason to move.

While this is all true in general, Musk is known to be quite impulsive and his decisions are not always financially best (they're pretty disastrous for X). If anyone would move their company due to personal politics, it's him.

Wouldn't someone with a fiduciary duty also have a responsibility to not chase away major sources of revenue such as advertisers on twitter? Musk seems to have been working to chase them away with past comments https://www.thedailybeast.com/elon-musk-tells-advertisers-who-quit-x-twitter-to-go-fck-yourself and the recent lawsuit.

Some "move the company" decisions have other causes. My employer, which had about 4,000 people at the time, was owned by an authentically Texas-based based company in the 1990s, which demanded we move our HQ to the same city as theirs. This happened, but only about a hundred people relocated; all the operational sites stayed where they were. We were sold in the early 2000s, but the HQ is still in Texas, because there hasn't been a good reason to move it.

My answer isn't Musk specific. I am not his advisor or his shrink. By all means, by all means keep DVing my answer without explaination.

I didn't downvote but I suspect the downvotes came because your post reads exactly like the right-wing leanings OP asks about although the facts on the ground don't seem to support that such a large business/ jobs exodus from California is actually happening.

How does the first paragraph have any relevance to this question?

@Jen The first paragraph was to address comments. I appreciate your question and am glad to clarify. I am all for questioning logic in a productive way. Bringing the Middle East into the Q about CA / business and then saying I make "black and white judgments..." is off putting. The paragraph is my way of saying that I don't have to agree with everyone, but I try to respect them. I would the same in return without sounding preachy.

But an answer need only address the question. There is no need to address characterizations about you in your answer. It detracts from its focus on answering the question.

@Jen - I had two choices, address each comment one at a time or all at once. When a comment is logic and about the answer I will spend the responding to each comment. Like I am with you. You are asking about my logic and we are being polite to each each other. I believe that I gave a business viewpoint on the uncertainties that affect businesses. For that effect I received 5 negative comments that IMO didn't address any flaws in my answer. Not a single positive comment or upvote. I consider my time valuable. My clients consider my time valuable. So, addressed the group at once.

You don't need to address comments that don't alter your answer, though. You should just ignore or flag. It makes your answer worse to address comments that you find irrelevant to the answer's content in the answer itself.

All right, +1, because companies have indeed cited those reasons for leaving.  But this answer would look a lot better without its uber-whiny first paragraph.  You need to remember that people aren't obligated to comment on why they downvoted - not least because that not infrequently leads to animosity.  Maybe the DVers just didn't like to be told that CA has high taxes and regulations and it is their right to hold that opinion.

Also, fiduciary duty is a subject that bring out a lot of hot air out of people.  Per Harvard Biz : “Rather than require specific outcomes–such as achieving maximum share price–fiduciary duties are largely about conduct, process, and motivation,”  i.e. it is, among other things, a recurring strawman by anti-capitalists to argue that a business leader is obligated to f..k everyone to maximize shareholder value.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica  Violation of it can put some in jail.  Nothing to do with IP4M's comment - On another note: A pet peave of mine is the lack of understanding that LONG TERM a business must treat well: Shareholders, Vendors, Employees, and Customers.  Irk any one (or more) of these groups and the business can't survive.
